# NSArrayController binding details in 1:many:many model

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-bindings

I've got a simple program illustrating what I am trying to do in my real program. I've got a 1 to many relationship of 1 to many relationships, and I cannot get multiple selection editing to work properly if the top level has multiple selections:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>

@interface ManyMany : NSObject

@property int value1;
@property int value2;

@end

@implementation ManyMany

- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    ManyMany *m = [[ManyMany allocWithZone:zone] init];
    m.value1 = self.value1;
    m.value2 = self.value2;

    return m;
}

- (BOOL)isEqual:(ManyMany *)other {
    if (other == nil) {
        return NO;
    }

    if (self.value1 == other.value1 && self.value2 == other.value2) {
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}

@end

@interface Many : NSObject

@property NSArray< ManyMany * > *manyManys;

@end

@implementation Many

@end

@interface One : NSObject 

@property NSArray< Many * > *manys;

@end

@implementation One

@end

@interface MyObserver : NSObject

@property NSObject *value;

@end

@implementation MyObserver

@end

int main()
{
    One *one = [[One alloc] init];
    one.manys = @[ [[Many alloc] init], [[Many alloc] init] ];
    one.manys[0].manyManys = @[ [[ManyMany alloc] init], [[ManyMany alloc] init] ];
    one.manys[1].manyManys = @[ [[ManyMany alloc] init], [[ManyMany alloc] init] ];

    NSArrayController *manyController = [[NSArrayController alloc] init];
    manyController.objectClass = [Many class];

    NSArrayController *manyManyController = [[NSArrayController alloc] init];
    manyManyController.objectClass = [ManyMany class];

    [manyController bind:NSContentArrayBinding toObject:one withKeyPath:@"manys" options:nil];
    [manyManyController bind:NSContentArrayBinding toObject:manyController withKeyPath:@"selection.manyManys" options:nil];

    MyObserver *o = [[MyObserver alloc] init];
    [o bind:@"value" toObject:manyManyController withKeyPath:@"selection.value1" options:nil];

    [manyController setSelectionIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0,2)]];
    [manyManyController setSelectionIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0,2)]];

    [manyManyController setValue:@(2) forKeyPath:@"selection.value1"];

    NSLog(@"contents:");
    Many *m;
    for (m in one.manys) {
        NSLog(@"many @ %p", m);
        ManyMany *mm;
        for (mm in m.manyManys) {
            NSLog(@"manyMany @ %p", mm);
            NSLog(@" %d %d", mm.value1, mm.value2);
        }
    }
}
```

The output of this shows the first group of 2 are properly set, not all four. If I change the contents binding of the ManyManyController to `selectedObjects.manyManys` instead, then set setValue:forKeyPath: will properly set all 4, however the binding to the observer will crash.

What am I fundamentally missing?

Answer (score 1):

1. You're missing the Content Array For Multiple Selection binding.

> An indexed collection specifying the items that the NSArrayController treats as its content objects when the contentArray or contentObject binding returns the multiple selection marker.

```
[manyManyController bind:NSContentArrayForMultipleSelectionBinding toObject:manyController withKeyPath:@"selection.@unionOfArrays.manyManys" options:nil];
```

2. The contentArray binding doesn't return the multiple selection marker because the `Many.manys`s are equal. Switching `alwaysUsesMultipleValuesMarker` on will fix this but will also disable multiple selection editing of attributes of `Many`.

```
manyController.alwaysUsesMultipleValuesMarker = YES;
```

3. Select all 4 four `ManyMany`s.

```
[manyManyController setSelectionIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0,4)]];
```

Comment: Thank you!! I was half there by trying step 1 before I asked but missed the fact I’d need to set always use multiple as per point 2. (Selecting the first two is a typo in my test program; the actual program has a UI where I was selecting all 4).